# how to benefit from my certificates to update

Tags: android, google-play

Peace be upon you
I want update my app in google play store
but they refuse my release due that keystore is different from old keystore
but i lost old keystore

and app signing is enabled in my account
how i can benefit from these certificates to restore my old keystore.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWMld.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Play App Signing you can contact Google Play support and get them to update your upload key to a new one. Follow the instructions [on the help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) in the section called "Create a new upload key".